# Does anime really account for 60% of the world’s animation-based entertainment?

Tags: culture

I see some variation of this self-proclaimed unattributed fact on the web:

> Anime accounts for 60% of the world's animation-based entertainment. So successful is animation in Japan, that there are almost 130 voice-acting schools in the country.

How true is this fact? What was the original source? What about the other 40%?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It comes from [this document published by JETRO](https://www.jetro.go.jp/en/reports/market/pdf/2005_35_r.pdf) (Japan External Trade Organization) where it says (page 7):

> International sales data is not exact, but around 60% of the anime shown worldwide is
>   made in Japan, according to a METI report issued in January 2004. Twenty Japanese anime programs
>   were being broadcast on American TV as of March 2003.

(Note that "anime" in this context probably means "animation")

The 60% figure was also quoted by [Jim Frederick's article in Time Asia "What's Right with Japan"](http://web.archive.org/web/20100403090055/http://www.time.com/time/asia/2003/cool_japan/story.html):

> Pokémon has supplanted Astroboy in the hearts of schoolkids in more than 65 countries, and 60% of the world's animated-cartoon series are made in Japan.

Though, no source was provided.

---

The number of voice-acting schools was attributed to:

> Terumitsu Otsu and Mary Kennard (April 27, 2002). "The art of voice acting". The Daily Yomiuri. p. 11.

Source fetched from [the Voice Acting in Japan wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_acting_in_Japan).

---

I don't know how to account for the other 40% of animated entertainment. Maybe if you're able to get a copy of the METI report that was issued in January 2004, [which doesn't seem to be listed on their website](http://www.meti.go.jp/english/report/previous_report.html).

Comment: I managed to track down [a different METI report](http://www.meti.go.jp/policy/media_contents/downloadfiles/kobetsugenjyokadai/genjyoukadai1215.pdf) that also claims that "60% of animation is produced in Japan". Unfortunately, it does not elaborate on that claim. Somebody with access to a proper dead-tree library would probably be able to track down the report in question.